# Rc<RefCell<T>>のTを編集できない

Tags: rust

`Rc`と`RefCell`を使って、以下のように動作確認をしていました。

```rust
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    num: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Test { num: 100 }));
    let a1 = a.clone();
    a.borrow_mut().num = 100;
    a1.borrow_mut().num = 100;
    println!("a: {:?}", a);
    println!("a1: {:?}", a1);
}
```

すると、100を代入している部分で以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
error[E0609]: no field `num` on type `&mut Rc<RefCell<Test>>`
  --> src/main.rs:13:20
   |
13 |     a.borrow_mut().num = 100;
   |                    ^^^ unknown field
```

以下の記事を参考に動作を見ていたのですが、このようなエラーは出てなく疑問に思っています。

[Rust の Cell, RefCell を整理する](https://zenn.dev/tan_y/articles/307533011ac2c0)

こちらどのように修正すれば`Test`構造体の内容を変更できるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
error[E0609]: no field `num` on type `&mut Rc<RefCell<Test>>`
```

エラーメッセージを見ると、[RefCell::borrow_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) を呼んでから .num にアクセスしたいところで、意図と異なり [Rc の BorrowMut::borrow_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.BorrowMut.html#tymethod.borrow_mut) が呼ばれてしまっているようです。
BorrowMut トレイトを use しないでおけば、 Rc に borrow_mut メソッドがないため勝手に参照外し (deref) が発生し、内側の RefCell の borrow_mut が呼ばれるようになります。

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=38e0fb2bb26a7ccf83733f8658300691

Comment: あるいは `RefCell::borrow_mut(&a).num = 100;` のように利用するメソッドを明示するようにしてもよいですね。どうして `BorrowMut` をインポートしないといけないときに便利です。